# Who is Jesus' Father?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Jesus talks about his father a lot. Is it Yahweh? How do we know that when Jesus says, "My father" he means Yahweh from the Old Testament?

Comment: I got a good clear answer for a reasonable question. The question is NOT obvious, despite the fact that it's what's most christians belief. I mean the verses supporting it are pretty scarce.

Comment: It seems that people here think that I am up to no good for questioning things that should be questioned.

Comment: And the more I think something should be questioned, the more everyone else think it shouldn't be. I am frustrated here.

Comment: Jesus knows the 'Father' but do we know what He means when He uses that term - John 8: 55? Is there a question left if we know that? Using the term Y...h makes yours a loaded question because it belongs in a specific religious context unlike the terms Lord God (Adonay Elohim) that it is derived from. Maybe edit 'Y...h' to 'God' or direct your question to a specific religious group.

Comment: The problem you seem to be encountering is not so much what you are asking but the phrasing of questions. Using this question for example; as stated 'Who is Jesus father?' In most people's mind that is a contentious question, and even before reading the remainder of what you ask there is a hostile reaction. It could have been better phrased 'Does the Bible say that Yahweh is who Jesus refers to as my father?' Perhaps you might get some pointers on asking questions from "Help". The initial impression is paramount to getting good answers.

Comment: The problem with using the word God instead of YHWH is because the original bible in hebrew wrote YHWH and translators often use "the LORD" or "God" in ways that hide controversy. So I stick with the closest to the original text. Whatever the original text say, not what we think the original text should mean.

Comment: John 5:18 ”18 For this reason they tried all the more to kill him;(K) not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.(L)

Comment: Are you looking for a definitive scriptural source linking the YHWY word found in the OT with any reference to that same exact word in the NT? I wondered that myself but it seems there is some debate about the translation of YHWY being a proper name and any reference to God by proper name in the NT. You could be in for a long debate here.

Comment: YHWH... sorry. mistyped twice!

Comment: The Lord Thy Holy God.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple ways, though not all of them are obvious in the English translation.

Jesus refers to himself with 'I AM' in a manner as to make a direct connection to Yahweh from the Old Testament.

> “Very truly I tell you,” Jesus answered, “before Abraham was born, I am!” John 8:58
>
> God said to Moses, “I am who I am. This is what you are to say to the Israelites ‘I am has sent me to you.’”      Exodus 3:14

http://www.hebrew4christians.com/Names_of_G-d/YHVH/yhvh.html

**EDIT**
Somebody wanted more specificity, so if you read the whole passage Jesus says clearly to the Jews...

> Jesus replied, “If I glorify myself,(BN) my glory means nothing. My Father, whom  you claim as your God, is the one who glorifies me.    John 8:54

Doesn't get much clearer than that. The God of the Jews is Yaweh. Jesus says that the God they claim is his Father.

Comment: Your statement only prove that Jesus is Yahveh ("I AM"), if indeed your interpretation of that verse is correct. The original question asks how we know that Yahveh is being referred to when Jesus says "my father."

Comment: Now, I would say that John 8:54 is a good answer.

Comment: Ah yes. John 8 is pretty clear. Any other verse?

Comment: Your statement, 'the God of the Jews is Y...h' is curiously correct. 'God' with a capital is only ever applied to one entity and that together with 'Lord' is the Divine Name expressed in the four Hebrew letters Y,H,W,H. (Note the absence of vowels.) The root is 'to be' therefore 'eternal' and 'creator' therefore 'father'. God is 'Eternal Father' of Jesus and all Jews.

Comment: Those capital letter God and "the LORD" is not in the original language. The correct way to transliterate YHWH would be YHWH if it's a proper name. It could also be translated. In any case, "the LORD" is not a correct translation or transliteration. Saying "the LORD" would imply Ha Eloah, or Ha Elohim, or Ha Adonai, which is simply not what the original language is. This may cause confusion for our atheist brothers that think ancient judaism could be polytheistic.

Comment: This is a quote:'Lord is the usual English translation of Adonay. Adonay is the prescribed traditional reading of the Divine Name expressed in the four Hebrew letters YHWH ...' Elohim is normally translated as 'God' and relates to the creator and governor. Adonay describes His eternity, close relationship to humanity and lovingkindness, Elohim His creativity, justice and rulership. By using the term 'father', Jesus combined these two 'funtions' in one as a child perceives his or her (idealized) father.

Comment: @Sharen Eayrs, "Those capital letter God and 'the LORD' is not in the original language." Yes it is, sort of.  The Jews pointed the letters JHVH with the vowel points of Adonay, to indicate that its to be read as Adonay. This is of course where the pronunciation Jehovah came from: that's how its actually written in the Hebrew manuscripts, as Jehovah, not just YHWH and not Yahweh.  But the argument goes that those vowel points are not really there for pronunciation but as pointers to tell you to replace the name with the word Adonay (the LORD).

Comment: That vowel points are also recent invention and not on original copy of the bible. Assuming the "original" bible is indeed inerrant. In any case, it would be Ha Adonay, rather than just Adonay. Name is used to differentiate an object from many similar objects. Mars' moon have names. Our moon is simply called, "the moon". Replacing YHWH with "the LORD" imply that there is only one "LORD". That implication is not on the original text. It's hiding controversy. And it's dishonest.

Comment: Anyway, is this the only verse in the whole gospel where Jesus claims that Yahweh is his father? I mean he seems to talk a lot about God being our father too and tell us to pray starting from "our father in heaven..." Who is our father?

Comment: If you believe that ...... (insert name according to choice) is the creator of everything, then that being is 'our father' if not, who cares. Jesus specifically meant the Jewish God.

Comment: Any other verses suggesting that Yahweh is Jesus' dad?

Comment: John 5:18 ”18 For this reason they tried all the more to kill him;(K) not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.(L)."

Comment: Just FYI, "Adonai" is the plural personal possessive of "adon", therefore translating as "Our Lords". Being a possessive it is already definite, so adding the definite article is grammatically incorrect. Saying "Ha Adonai" is equivalent to saying "the Our Lords" in English.